# Using an Emacs frame as a GTK widget?

Tags: gtk3

I've been brainstorming some ideas towards developing some IDE support for developing with the Ruby programming language and Emacs. I was considering a possibility of using an Emacs frame as a UI widget in a Ruby application on X Windows platforms. I wonder if there may be any particular support for this, with Emacs builds using a GTK widget toolkit?

I've read of the [Xembed support for Emacs](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsXembed). I assume that this might be available to an Emacs build with Athena or Lucid widgets. Maybe it would also apply to an Emacs build using a GTK toolkit?

Outside of the Xembed linking, is it possible to use an Emacs frame as a GTK widget, in a GTK application?

There is a bit of documentation in the Emacs manual about using [GTK resources in Emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/GTK-resources.html). I understand that for some Emacs builds, it may even be possible [to use GTK WebKit under browse-url](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsXWidgets), in Emacs.

Conversely, if it may be possible to use an Emacs frame as a GTK widget, then perhaps it could be used as such in the GTK bindings for Ruby or any other general programming language?

#### Update

So to speak, maybe Xembed is the way to go, with this. There may be some additional GTK support available for Xembed, e.g with [Gtk.Plug](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk3/class.Plug.html) in the embedded Emacs process and [Gtk.Socket](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk3/class.Socket.html) in the embedding application.

As a point of reference, @bert at GitHub has posted [a gist illustrating how to use Gtk.Socket](https://gist.github.com/bert/809126) in an application. The C code in the gist uses gVim as an embedded client application.

Presumably, the `Gtk.Plug` handling could be managed within Emacs, using a special-purpose Emacs module for this or e.g [emacs-ffi](https://github.com/tromey/emacs-ffi). Maybe it's managed already, under Emacs with GTK widgets - e.g in [Emacs `gtkutil.c`](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/3af9e84ff59811734dcbb5d55e04e1fdb7051e77/src/gtkutil.c#L1224).

Towards using Emacs as an embedded text editor for source-oriented text editing, whether in Ruby applications or otherwise, the Xembed support might be the thing?